# pyspark repeat function pass parameter dynamically based on column data length

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Requirement :** Need to populate 4 digit row number with prefix 000

**Example :** 0001,0002.....0011,0012

Here I am repeating number of zero to prefix based on the length of the row number value i.e in column `PAGENO`

```
df.select(F.repeat(F.lit(0), 3))
```

The value 3 needs to change dynamically based on row number value.

My idea to achive dynamic `0` replication:

```
df.select(F.repeat(F.lit(0),(4 - F.length(df["PAGENO"]))))
```

getting error:

> 'Column' object is not callable

When passing any column or parameter instead of just numeric 3 as no of times repeat should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it within an SQL expression:

```
df.select(F.expr("repeat(0, length(PAGENO))")).show()
```

However, if I've correctly understood your question you want to use [`lpad`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#lpad) function. Here's an example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,), (2,), (10,), (12,), (11,)], ["PAGENO"])

df1 = df.withColumn("PAGENO_2", F.expr("lpad(PAGENO, 4, '0')"))

df1.show()
#+------+--------+
#|PAGENO|PAGENO_2|
#+------+--------+
#|     1|    0001|
#|     2|    0002|
#|    10|    0010|
#|    12|    0012|
#|    11|    0011|
#+------+--------+
```

Comment: thanks @blackbishop , this made my day easy.

in extension to the above requirement , i need to reset the  "PAGENO" once it reaches to 9999 and start from 0001 freshly. how to achieve this any suggestion?

Comment: solution at this link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70270567/pyspark-row-number-reset-for-every-4-digits-completion