# pyspark row number reset for every 4 digits completion

Tags: pyspark, row-number

I am applying row_number on particular column based on one column partition. how to reset the row number to starting number 1 once it reaches 999 through pyspark?

| partcode | row number |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 0001 |
| 12345 | 0002 |
| 12345 | 0003 |
| 12345 | 9999 -- Reaches max |
| 12345 | 0001 |
| 12345 | 0002 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After generating `row number`:

1. Subtract `1` from `row number` to get row number starting from zero
2. Apply modulo operation using the `cut-off value (9999)`
3. Add `1` to the modulo result to get the `row number` starting from 1 and wrapping back to 1 for row number `cut-off value + 1`

> In my example I have used a smaller cutoff value of `3`

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([(12345, )for _ in range(0, 10)], ("partcode", ))

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("partcode").orderBy("partcode")

cut_off = 3

df.withColumn("row number", F.row_number().over(window_spec))\
  .withColumn("row number", F.lpad(((F.col("row number") - F.lit(1)) % F.lit(cut_off)) + F.lit(1), 4, '0'))\
  .show()
```

### Output

```
+--------+----------+
|partcode|row number|
+--------+----------+
|   12345|      0001|
|   12345|      0002|
|   12345|      0003|
|   12345|      0001|
|   12345|      0002|
|   12345|      0003|
|   12345|      0001|
|   12345|      0002|
|   12345|      0003|
|   12345|      0001|
+--------+----------+
```